# Making delay in java

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 `JLabel`s, I want to display one by one after 1sec (1000mls). `Thread.sleep(1000);` will not work. I don't know, the three JLabels will display after completing the task (3 JLabels display simultaneously after 3 sec.). How can I solve it?  Can timer make delay?

Comment: Thread.sleep works fine, you just can't use it in the GUI event loop unless you want to GUI to lock up.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/33105688/3111870

Comment: Just use Swing timer unless you are doing something sophisticated like a video game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
  int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this:

```
package demo.javase.swing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ThreeJLabelsDemo extends JPanel {

    private Timer timer;

    private JButton startButton;

    private int count;

    public ThreeJLabelsDemo() {
        super(new FlowLayout());

        startButton = new JButton("Add 3 JLabels");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                startButton.setEnabled(false);
                timer.start();
            }

        });
        add(startButton);

        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                add(new JLabel("Label" + count++));
                revalidate();
                repaint();
                timer.stop();
                if (count < 3) {
                    timer.restart();
                } else {
                    startButton.setEnabled(true);
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Three JLabels Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new ThreeJLabelsDemo());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

I believe in such cases, you must use `javax.swing.Timer` as `Thread.sleep(long)` will simply block the app.